# jmpi instruction in NIOS

Tags: nios

Apparently, the NIOS instruction `jmpi 0x87654320` would be `0x76543201` in machine code (op-code = `0x01`, immediate = `0x1D950C8` (`0x765432`*4)). However, if J type instructions in NIOS have a word address as the 26-bit immediate, how does the computer know that it's telling it to jump to `0x87654320` and not, say `0x07654320`?

Comment: See the instruction documentation: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683620/current/jmpi.html It says "PC ←  (PC[31..28] : IMM26 x 4)"

Comment: @RaymondChen Wait, so would I be correct to say that It can only make the programme counter jump to an address that's between `0x80000000` & `0x8FFFFFFF` (inclusive)?

Comment: The high 4 bits come from the current PC, so you can jump to any address in the same 256MB block.